# dropzone autoProcessQueue not getting picked up

Tags: javascript, html, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone on my page to upload images, but for some reason it is not picking up the option "autoProcessQueue"

I pasted this exact code in my page and it still uploads as soon as i select the image from this tutorial: https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Upload-all-files-with-a-button

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {

  // Prevents Dropzone from uploading dropped files immediately
  autoProcessQueue: false,

  init: function() {
    var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-all")
        myDropzone = this; // closure

    submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      myDropzone.processQueue(); // Tell Dropzone to process all queued files.
    });

    // You might want to show the submit button only when 
    // files are dropped here:
    this.on("addedfile", function() {
      // Show submit button here and/or inform user to click it.
    });

  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and it turned out that I was using an outdated version of Dropzone. The `autoProcessQueue` feature was only added in v3.6.0, so make sure you use at least that.

Answer (score -1):

You have to look into ur code that u have made
**autoProcessQueue: false,**

**make it true**

**autoProcessQueue: true,**
and also check this parameter's value in your **dropzone.js** 
and change it there also, It will definitely work..

Comment: You're missing the point. he needs `autoProcessQueue = false` because he wants to submit it with a submit button, not automatically.